# Inbound Twllio SMS to trigger LogicApp

Tags: twilio, azure-logic-apps

Unfortunately Twilio does not have an inbound action trigger in Azure Logic App.
Using TwiLM , is this possible to trigger the Logic App when receiving a txt ?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic app doesn't provide the Twilio  trigger, so couldn't implement it directly.

However Twilio has a feature under the Phone Numbers. In the messaging, it could configure the Twilio Phone Number to use a Webhook when a message comes in to call the endpoint with an Http Post. And with this you could set a HTTP trigger logic app, and set the Twilio endpoint with the Logic app url.

[image]

Further more information, you could refer to this blog:[Triggering an Azure Logic App by SMS messages with Twilio](https://platform.deloitte.com.au/articles/triggering-an-azure-logic-app-with-an-sms-using-twilio).